# WordPress Rest API Escapes Returned URLs Forward Slash

Tags: rest-api, json

I have created an endpoint via `register_rest_route()` that gets serialized data from the DB. When it is returned, all of the URL strings are escaped. `https:\/\/s.w.org\/plugins\/geopattern-icon\/action-scheduler.svg`. It seems this is because returned values are passed through PHPs `json_encode()` function. How would I return the URLs, so they are not escaped `https://s.w.org/plugins/geopattern-icon/action-scheduler.svg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no different to when `&amp;` in raw HTML is displayed as `&`, **it's standard JSON encoding**, and is resolved by *decoding* the JSON. Any application that is unable to handle this has probably forgotten to parse the JSON response.

For example:

```js
const url = JSON.parse( '"https:\/\/s.w.org\/plugins\/geopattern-icon\/action-scheduler.svg"' );
console.log( url );
```

Will print the URL as you expected. JSON decode then grab that value from the resulting array/object.